# Bash - need to write data to a file based on output of a command in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script which checks IP Addresses in a file line by line and executes a command with that IP saved in a variable .
I wanted to add a few lines of bash which would write that IP to a new file when the output of the command is something specific. 
I would be grateful if anyone shed some light on this matter.

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: What else do you need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you stored the output of the command to a variable named `output`, you can do something like:

```
# $output is the output you got
# $expected is the expected value
# $IP is IP you just checked

if [ "$output" == "$expected" ]; then
    echo $IP >> file.txt
fi
```

replace `file.txt` with the name of the file name you prefer.

Comment: does $expected have to be a variable or can i just write it ?

Comment: a variable. but alternatively you can just put whatever you like between the quotes, as a string

Comment: Thanks. Worked great. Now that I pay attention, I realize its simple .